# How to use a QStyledItemDelegate to render QIcons for a column?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am using a QTableView and QSqlTableModel to show data from a sqlite DB.  In the DB (and model) there is a column with fields that contain either paths ie: '/home/foo/bar.txt' or nothing. For this column in the view I would like to render one icon for items with a path, and a different icon for items with nothing (and not render the actual data/path in the view at all).
I *think I* need to set up a QStyledItemDelegate to render icons in place of the data, but the staritemdelelgate from the included examples highlights the editor function of the delegate (which I do not want) without shedding any light on how to render QIcons (or maybe I am just missing it).  I have looked through the API, but I am unclear as to how to subclass a QStyledItemDelegate, or even if I need to for this use case.
Some guidance on whether this is a viable method, or an example of how to use a QStyledItemDelegate to render icons for a column (preferably in python) would be appreciated.

EDIT: Petr's post solved the issue.  A full implementation of the situation I described, based on Petr's solution is:

```
def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):  
    if index.column() == 2:  
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:  
            filename = super(MovieModel, self).data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)  
            if not filename == '':  
                return self.yes_icon  
            else:  
                return self.no_icon    
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:  
            return ''  
    #Other columns/roles:  
    return super(MovieModel, self).data(index, role)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subclassing the delegate, you can subclass the model, and return the icon in the item's `DecorationRole`.

Untested sketch of solution:

```
class IconModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.column() == FILENAME_COLUMN_INDEX:
             if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
                  filename = super(IconModel, self).data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
                  return icon_for_filename(filename)
             elif role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                  return ''
        # Other columns/roles:
        return super(IconModel, self).data(index, role)
```

Subclassing delegates is much more of a pain.

Comment: Subclassing the model worked without adding a delegate. Thanks!